# expandable listview design

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I have a present design in listview to display a list of programs. But if the program is a series, the programs must be grouped into a sigle entity and when clicked on the series the programs should be populated under it.
As of now I have an arraylist which has details of series ID, program name etc. The programs which have same series ID should be grouped as a single series, rest should be shown as normal items. When clicked on this series, all those programs which have the seriesID of the clicked series, should be shown under the clicked item.
Any insight into using expandable listview for the same is very useful:)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use ExpandableListView.

You will need to implement a custom ExpandableListAdapter. It's pretty straightforward. Instead of a single list element, you have to implement methods for both children and groups (getChildCount(), getGroupCount(), etc.), and methods that show the relationship between a group and a child (e.g., getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition)).

If you model your data correctly, it should be simple to implement. In your case, you'd want to have a Series object (the group) that contains one or more Program objects (the children).

One stumbling block for you might be that some programs are not in a series. I don't know there's a way to mix grouped and non-grouped items inside the expandable list. You might need to create a "non-grouped programs" group.

In this case, you could implement your own "grouped list view". It would not be too tough. Your object model is like,

```
class ListItem
  class ProgramItem extends ListItem
  SeriesItem extends ListItem
```

is ProgramItem, you have method like,

```
getSeries()
```

That can return null, which is how you tell if it's contained in a particular series, or not contained. Now the neat part. You make ProgramItem and SeriesItem comparable, and sort the list containing them. the logic to order the programs under the correct series is nicely encapsulated in the implementation of `compareTo()`.

Then in `getView()`, you do an instanceof and render either the group or child view accordingly. if the ProgramItem is contained, you indent it, or whatever.

Comment: Yes, even Imn't getting as how to model the data of groupedprograms and nin-grouped programs

Answer (score 0):

To use expandable List view need to create Adapter class as want to display expandable list view create a class BaseExpandableListAdapter

1.with in this you have to use overridden functions 
1.getchildview
2.getGroupview

1.getChildCount and getGroupcount return the length of parent and child

See you have programs and series 
create two arraylist programs and one series 
one hash map to find whether particular program is having series or not

then with in Base expandable list adapter

1.with in getGroupCount 
return the length of programs arraylist
2.with in the length of getchildernCount
return the length of program[position].length (if that program has series use hashmap)